# Is there a standard tool to fill a queue in rabbit mq for testing

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a tool I can use to fill an arbitrary queue in rabbit mq to see if my consumer is working correctly?

I can of course write a test publisher in code, but if there is already something I can use out of the box, it would be convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,
You can use the RabbitMQ perftest:
https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-perf-test/stable/htmlsingle/

getting started:
https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-perf-test/stable/htmlsingle/#basic-usage

Binary:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test/releases

Comment: It seems the tool is sending all messages to the root virtual host, is there a way to change that? I cannot find that in the documentiation. I can of course adapt my client to use root, but the original set up is not that way.

Comment: Also I would like to specify the connection that actually has password credentials and is located on another server. I do not think that is possible with the tool.

Comment: Please read the documentation and `java -jar perf-test-2.20.0.jar --help` you can find everything you need